# Php include add title tag

Tags: php

Okay people, its something very common the only thing is that I have no idea how to deal with it. i have a file "login.php" the codes within the file are

```
<div><textarea>Eneter your description</textarea></div>
```

I have a second file name "index.php" and the html inside it are

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SMO</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("login.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem i am facing is that, when php include login.php it also add a `<title></title>` tag hence i am left with two title tags. 
Please help me sort it out. I know its a kid things. but just could not figure out how to solve this.

Comment: see the answer it contain a texarea and a div. i have posted

Comment: Take a look at a simple MVC framework instead of cosing everything yourself from scratch. There, check out some simple examples for the views. This has been solved a million times before...

Comment: Your posted code will not add a second `<title>` tag; PHP doesn't add any HTML elements automatically, it's just sticking text strings together.

Comment: @arkascha "I'm having trouble using these scissors" "Rather than cutting everything yourself, take a look at a factory production line" I know you meant well, but for beginners  code written from scratch is a lot easier to understand and learn from.

Answer (score 2):

**login.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SMO</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><textarea>Eneter your description</textarea></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SMO</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("login.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this your code?
If yes, you don't have to add the `<title>` in your login.php page.Remove `<title>` and it'll work fine.
If no, please include your code in your question.

So your **login.php** page should be like

```
<div><textarea>Eneter your description</textarea></div>
```